# how to get parameter of href in ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i am trying to get parameter of `href` in ajax.

```
<a href="index.php?del_id=<?php echo $c_id; ?>" class="delete" value="<?php echo $c_id ?>">Delete</a></li>
```

now i am trying to get `del_id` in ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".delete").click(function(){
        var url = ($(this).attr('href'));
        var id=    getURLParameter(url,'del_id');
        if(confirm('Are you sure to remove this file ?'))
        {
            $.ajax({
               url: 'maincode.php',
               type: 'GET',
               data: {id: id},
               success: function(data) 
                {
                    alert("file removed successfully");  
                },
                error:function()
                {
                 alert('Something is wrong');
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

but after adding `getURLParameter` code is not getting execute further.please help me.

Comment: What do you expect `getURLParameter` to do? It isn't part of the standard browser JS environment.

Comment: "but after adding getURLParameter code is not getting execute further" — Are there any error messages in the Console of the browsers developer tools?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to overthink this, the parameter is already in the url :

```
---- href="index.php?del_id=<?php echo $c_id; ?>"

$(".delete").click(function(){
    var url = ($(this).attr('href')); // this already has the id in it 
    if(confirm('Are you sure to remove this file ?'))
    {
        $.ajax({
           url: 'maincode.php',
           type: 'GET',
           // remove this, the data is in the url -- data: {id: id}, 
           success: function(data) 
            {
                alert("file removed successfully");  
            },
            error:function()
            {
             alert('Something is wrong');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

On the server, there will be a get parameter called del_id 
if you need the parameter to be id, change the url to :

```
index.php?id=<?php echo $c_id; ?>
```

If you really want to have the data populated by code, use data parameters

```
<a href="#" data-del-id="<?php echo $c_id; ?>" data-url="index.php" >

// JAVASCRIPT SIDE: 
var url = $(this).data('url'); // OR : $(this).attr('data-url');
var id  = $(this).data('del-id'); // OR : $(this).attr('data-del-id');
```

I hope this makes sense